# Android layouts, drawables, and resolution, what is the best way?

Tags: android

I d like to develop to screen resolutions:

854*480
800*480
480*320

what is the correct /res structure for this?

```
#1
drawable-854x480
drawable-800x480
drawable-480x320

layout-854x480
layout-800x480
layout-480x320

or

#2
drawable-hdpi-854x480
drawable-hdpi-800x480
drawable-mdpi-480x320

layout-hdpi-854x480
layout-hdpi-800x480
layout-mdpi-480x320

or

#3
drawable-hdpi-long
drawable-hdpi-notlong
drawable-mdpi

layout-hdpi-long
layout-hdpi-notlong
layout-mdpi
```

or else?

i am totally confused, because Galaxy S not use the "800x480" directory, why? I think Galaxy S i9000 is a 3.7 inch, 800*480 device..

I d like to optimize my program version 1.5

**update:** If i havent "drawable" and "layout" folders, then i get "resource not found exception"

---

So my probleme is this:

[Different resources for WVGA800 and WVGA854?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050390/different-resources-for-wvga800-and-wvga854)

anybody a solution for this?

Comment: The long vs notlong stuff isn't going to work here.  long is anything with an aspect ratio > 1.5.  Aspect ratio for 800x480 is 1.67, aspect ration for 854x480 is 1.78, so both resolutions are marked 'long'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drawable-hdpi-854x480
drawable-hdpi-800x480
drawable-mdpi-480x320

layout-854x480

put a single image in three different folder (HDPI(72*72),LDPI(48*48),MDPI(36*36)) with the fallowing ratio and put only one layout for that.
I hope this is help.

Comment: update: If i havent "drawable" and "layout" folders, then i get "resource not found exception", if I use long/notlong then in eclipse 3.7 WVGA and 3.7 FWVGA show me the "long" too. So WTF?

Answer (score 1):

Hello i think android drawable resolution is-

10" - 1280 X 800

7" - 1024 X 600

xhdpi - 960 x 720

hdpi - 800 X 480

mdpi - 480 X 320